# Android notification icon displays white in some devices, how to keep the icon colored

Tags: android, colors, notifications, icons

I have integrated FCM notification in my app, I am receiving the notifications also, I have set my Applications logo as notification icon, which is a colored logo. But in notification, it appears weird, depending upon the transparent portion of the image, and all the colored portion turns white.

I have also noticed that this problem occours in some devices independent of the versions. For the same OS version, the icon appears colored in samsung phone and appears white on the moto phone.

Please suggest.

Comment: There is 2 ways to  change the icons .
1 .To make Custom Notification , where you change the Icons.
2. Tom change in the manifiest .

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notif_icon" />